# Why is fragmentation level so huge in files that contain other filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, dd, sparse-files

I've just found out what [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) are and wanted to conduct some experiments on them. On wiki you can read that the files can get fragmented easily. I wanted to check how bad that is. I created a file in the following way:

```
# truncate -s 10G sparse-file
# mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -L sparse ./sparse-file
```

I mounted the sparse file, and I put a 600M file in it. The fragmentation level looks like this:

```
# filefrag -v "/media/Grafi/sparse-file"
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /media/Grafi/sparse-file is 10737418240 (2621440 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..    1032:      36864..     37896:   1033:
   1:     1043..    1043:      37907..     37907:      1:
   2:     1059..    1059:      37923..     37923:      1:
   3:     9251..    9256:      46115..     46120:      6:
   4:    32768..   32770:      51200..     51202:      3:      69632:
   5:    34816..   55295:      77824..     98303:  20480:      53248:
   6:    55296..   57343:     114688..    116735:   2048:      98304:
   7:    57344..   69631:     120832..    133119:  12288:     116736:
   8:    69632..   81919:     102400..    114687:  12288:     133120:
   9:    81920..   98303:     135168..    151551:  16384:     114688:
  10:    98304..   98306:      57344..     57346:      3:     151552:
  11:   100352..  112639:     151552..    163839:  12288:      59392:
  12:   112640..  145407:     165888..    198655:  32768:     163840:
  13:   145408..  163839:     198656..    217087:  18432:
  14:   163840..  163842:      40960..     40962:      3:     217088:
  15:   165888..  178175:     217088..    229375:  12288:      43008:
  16:   178176..  202751:     231424..    255999:  24576:     229376:
  17:   202752..  206847:     258048..    262143:   4096:     256000:
  18:   206848..  216756:     276480..    286388:   9909:     262144:
  19:   229376..  229378:      43008..     43010:      3:     299008:
  20:   294912..  294914:      53248..     53250:      3:     108544:
  21:   524288..  524288:      55296..     55296:      1:     282624:
  22:   819200..  819202:      61440..     61442:      3:     350208:
  23:   884736..  884738:      63488..     63490:      3:     126976:
  24:  1048576.. 1048577:      67584..     67585:      2:     227328:
  25:  1081344.. 1081391:      69632..     69679:     48:     100352:
  26:  1572864.. 1572864:      71680..     71680:      1:     561152:
  27:  1605632.. 1605634:      73728..     73730:      3:     104448:
  28:  2097152.. 2097152:      75776..     75776:      1:     565248:
  29:  2097167.. 2097167:      75791..     75791:      1:             last
/media/Grafi/sparse-file: 25 extents found
```

I thought it was because of the "sparse" feature, but it looks like all files that have other filesystems in them get fragmented in this way. Take a look at the following example:

Create a file full of zeroes:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=./zero bs=1M count=2048
```

Check its fragmentation level:

```
# filefrag -v /media/Grafi/zero
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /media/Grafi/zero is 2147483648 (524288 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..   32767:    6172672..   6205439:  32768:
   1:    32768..   65535:    6205440..   6238207:  32768:
   2:    65536..   98303:    6238208..   6270975:  32768:
   3:    98304..  118783:    6270976..   6291455:  20480:
   4:   118784..  151551:    6324224..   6356991:  32768:    6291456:
   5:   151552..  184319:    6356992..   6389759:  32768:
   6:   184320..  217087:    6389760..   6422527:  32768:
   7:   217088..  249855:    6422528..   6455295:  32768:
   8:   249856..  282623:    6455296..   6488063:  32768:
   9:   282624..  315391:    6488064..   6520831:  32768:
  10:   315392..  348159:    6520832..   6553599:  32768:
  11:   348160..  380927:    6553600..   6586367:  32768:
  12:   380928..  413695:    6586368..   6619135:  32768:
  13:   413696..  446463:    6619136..   6651903:  32768:
  14:   446464..  479231:    6651904..   6684671:  32768:
  15:   479232..  511999:    6684672..   6717439:  32768:
  16:   512000..  524287:    6717440..   6729727:  12288:             last,eof
/media/Grafi/zero: 2 extents found
```

So basically, this file has 17 extents, but from the human perspective, the file has two chunks

Now create a filesystem in this file:

```
# mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -L ext /media/Grafi/zero
```

Check its fragmentation again:

```
# filefrag -v /media/Grafi/zero

Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /media/Grafi/zero is 2147483648 (524288 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..     257:    5505024..   5505281:    258:
   1:      265..     265:    5505289..   5505289:      1:
   2:      272..     273:    5505296..   5505297:      2:
   3:      289..     289:    5505313..   5505313:      1:
   4:     8481..    8486:    5507361..   5507366:      6:    5513505:
   5:    32768..   32769:    5509120..   5509121:      2:    5531648:
   6:    98304..   98305:    5511168..   5511169:      2:    5574656:
   7:   163840..  163841:    5513216..   5513217:      2:    5576704:
   8:   229376..  229377:    5515264..   5515265:      2:    5578752:
   9:   262144..  262144:    5517312..   5517312:      1:    5548032:
  10:   294912..  294913:    5519360..   5519361:      2:    5550080: last
/media/Grafi/zero: 8 extents found
```

Does anyone know what actually happened here? Why the file got fragmented by creating a filesystem on it? What happened to the `length`?

**Added:**

The `mkfs.ext4` parameter `-Enodiscard` doesn't work. With this option I can see the structure of the file in `filefrag` (the zeroed blocks). But after creating the filesystem in this way, the file becomes fragmented for some reason no matter what. Maybe it's because of the filesystem metadata that is written, and it does something to the zeroed file. I don't know. But when I watch the output of `filefrag`, I can see that there is always +6 extents (in the case of 2G file). Maybe it's because of the superblock and its 5 copies? But this still doesn't explain why the whole file is fragmented -- it's still the same file.

There's another thing. When I recreate the filesystem in this file:

```
# mkfs.ext4 -Enodiscard /media/Grafi/zero
mke2fs 1.43 (17-May-2016)
/media/Grafi/zero contains a ext4 file system
        created on Thu Jun  2 13:02:28 2016
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Creating filesystem with 524288 4k blocks and 131072 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 6d58dddc-439b-4175-9af6-8628f0d2a278
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

The added extents magically disappear.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this was a bug in `mke2fs` that caused it to use `fallocate(fd, PUNCH_HOLE, ...)` instead of `fallocate(fd, DISCARD_ZERO, ...)` when zeroing out the space in the inode tables (even when `-E nodiscard` was used).

I submitted a bug report to the upstream `linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org` mailing list after verifying this behaviour locally, and got a patch within an hour, subject:

```
e2fprogs: block zero/discard cleanups
```

They should be included into the e2fsprogs-1.45 release, and *likely* the 1.44.x maintenance release.  If you want them in a vendor `e2fsprogs` release, I'd recommend to patch+build your e2fsprogs to verify this is working for you, report success to `linux-ext4` so that the patches will land sooner, then submit a bug report to your distro of choice so they pull the upstream patches into their releases.

Comment: Are you talking about this?
https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/cover/899596/

Comment: That's the one...  Ted said that it would also be included into the 1.44 maintenance release.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 test1
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Discarding device blocks: done
[...]
```

Now there's a hint. Let's see what the manual says:

```
-E extended-options
discard
  Attempt  to  discard blocks at mkfs time (discarding blocks initially is useful
  on solid state devices and sparse / thin-provisioned storage). When the  device
  advertises that discard also zeroes data (any subsequent read after the discard
  and before write returns zero), then mark all not-yet-zeroed  inode  tables  as
  zeroed.  This significantly speeds up filesystem initialization. This is set as
  default.
```

So, basically, mkfs knows that the old data on the underlying storage does not matter any more, so it can be discarded, and the underlying storage might have a better way do that, than just by overwriting with zeroes.
Which it has, the filesystem here can just forget about the data blocks.

After that, mkfs builds whatever filesystem structures it needs, in a somewhat random access pattern, resulting in new data blocks being allocated. The file is sparse again, and there's some fragmentation.

With `-Enodiscard` the result is perhaps what you expected:

```
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -Enodiscard test2
$ /usr/sbin/filefrag test2
test2: 2 extents found
```

Comment: I just updated the question, see it for info.